# Firebase onCreate function only returning one of many creations

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have this code:

```
exports.elevation = functions.database.ref('/ships_for_locations').onCreate(event => {

    const original = event.data.val();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(original) + "      event.data.val() ---------------");

    ...
```

The console output for `original` in the Firebase Functions log is:

> {"5eb0fbc824d2d48ce9e5cbc76a7a2e643b016009":{"ship15":{"g":"drt2k6vxuuwy","l":[42.247907072461054,-71.17265374654367]},"ship8":{"l":[42.24786474369262,-71.1727565570968],"g":"drt2k6vxdsf1"},"ship3":{"g":"drt2k6vxg21n","l":[42.247882900393094,-71.17272600000001]},"ship11":{"l":[42.24787704060876,-71.17272600000001],"g":"drt2k6vxer15"},"ship4":{"l":[42.247838578422375,-71.17272600000001],"g":"drt2k6vx7rcj"},"ship16":{"l":[42.24785870234929,-71.17277992860309],"g":"drt2k6vxd58v"},"ship1":{"l":[42.247865,-71.17270322375195],"g":"drt2k6vxeucg"},"ship7":{"l":[42.24787169684869,-71.17270156462881],"g":"drt2k6vxey55"},"ship13":{"l":[42.247842662420545,-71.17268807527044],"g":"drt2k6vxs0tq"},"ship2":{"g":"drt2k6vxdsge","l":[42.247865,-71.17275457694687]},"ship6":{"l":[42.247873403962814,-71.17273898101789],"g":"drt2k6vxdyrm"},"ship12":{"g":"drt2k6vx7m3h","l":[42.247825005009005,-71.17272600000001]},"ship14":{"l":[42.247875702512644,-71.17276722073039],"g":"drt2k6vxdqf7"},"ship9":{"l":[42.247865,-71.17272043195321],"g":"drt2k6vxekv5"},"ship5":{"g":"drt2k6vxkpbw","l":[42.247838767805725,-71.17269442665282]},"ship10":{"l":[42.247865,-71.17276938808422],"g":"drt2k6vxdkbe"}}}
>   event.data.val() ---------------

However (not matching with the data above), I am adding more than one item to the database reference with my script.

Here is a pastebin of what my database looks like for the `ships_for_locations` reference after my script runs - https://pastebin.com/Us4we4MU.

You can see there are multiple entries. However, when my `onCreate` function runs, it only returns one entry (as I showed at the beginning). Did I go over a quota or something? (I looked into it and couldn't find anything). I need all of the entries for `/ships_for_locations` so I can iterate through them. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From what you refer to the `0abf655263c3c9fed49387125c265120a4090be8` node holds a single object and this is created once, on the other hand you should have your different ships (ship1, ship2, ... ) directly under `ships_for_locations` reference with their own ids or `ship1, ship2, ..` as ids

Comment: The node does not hold only one object....it holds `ship1` - `ship15` and I am using those as ids as I think u are saying

Comment: i need to have the database structured how it is (ships NOT directly under `ships_for_locations`) because each of the nodes refers to another node in a different part of the database....and why would it matter how my database is structured beyond `/ships_for_locations`...im listening for any creations...once something is  created...it should have no problem changing the ship data under the node as long as my reference is correct...which it is....its just it doesnt retrieve all of the nodes in the first place...which seems like a fundamental problem with cloud functions...it is beta...

Comment: You listen to changes at the node only

Comment: `functions.database.ref('/ships_for_locations')` is where i am listening...so it should return whatever is under `ships_for_locations` correct? are u saying I should listen at `"/"`?

Comment: Any new creation of "direct" nodes, once per node

Comment: So...I am running a script that populates the database "all at once" would this be a problem for the function to recognize every node being created?

Comment: Yes loop on them after bulk creation or create as single entries

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165248/discussion-between-ewizard-and-alex-mounir).

Answer (score 0):

I changed the reference to `/ships_for_locations` to `/ships_for_locations/{pushId}` - and changed my code accordingly.